# How to check if a Linked List is full/computer is out of memory inside of an append function

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, append, out-of-memory

I am creating a doubly linked list. I have the program working, but I need to check if the list is full before appending any new nodes.
I know how to implement an isFull() function. But for this project that I am working on, I am not allowed to use the isFull() function.

I tried implementing what I had done before to check if a list is full:

```
try
{
    Node* n = new Node;
    delete(n);
    return false;
}
catch (bad_alloc)
{
    return true;
}
```

And that does work when it is in its own isFull() function. And I would call isFull() in my append function. But since I cannot create the isFull, how would I go about implementing that code and merge it into my append function?

This is my current append function:

```
void MyDLL::append(int i)
{
Node *n = new Node{ i, nullptr, nullptr };
if (head == nullptr)
{
    head = n;
    tail = n;
}
else
{
    n->prev = tail;
    tail->next = n;
    tail = n;
}
}
```

Comment: Check out [EAFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAFP).

Comment: I checked out that link. And it make sense. But does c++ have exception handling? Since the EAFP code is written for Python.

Comment: Checking for memory allocation failure is easier than checking if the platform is out of memory.  Search the internet for "virtual memory".  You will also need an operating system API since "out of memory" checking is not supported in the standard C++ language.

Comment: Nah, I did not mean that. I meant that if you check for if it's full (no memory), but at the time when you actually allocate (call new) the memory, you might still run out of memory. And per your question, C++ does have exception handling, and that's exactly what try-catch blocks do.

Comment: Your current `append` function already *"handles"* out of memory scenario by throwing `std::bad_alloc` when failing to execute `new Node{ i, nullptr, nullptr }`.

Comment: For what I understand of your question, you wanted to silently wrap a memory allocation failure. If that's what you want, you can either surround the `new` with a try block, or you can check out no-throw new operator, which returns `nullptr` on failure (same behavior as `malloc`).

Comment: Usually (well, no reference, personal opinion), libraries don't handle bad_alloc, because memory is something really out of their control (if you're interfacing C, then it's a totally different discussion), so you don't need to handle allocation failure, and just let the exception pop up and the client handle it.